# Questions about economic and human development in developing and the emerging countries (3rd world)

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if the questions related to socio-economic human development be posted on this site or on politics site? The questions in this category will be related to challenges leading to development in countries of Africa or India for example. Also the questions related to international affairs and international efforts to development (like the sustainable development goals of UN) be directed here?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on content of those questions.

1. This is Q&A site so you should ask answerable questions not questions that are meant to create discussion.
2. You should make sure that the content of question is **on-topic**. For definition of what is on/off topic on this site have a look at our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Note that on this site you should ask:

> something that a member can answer using facts, studies, economic theory and reasoning -not moral/political/religious/philosophical values.

The topic you mention seems to have overlapp with politics/philosophy and perhaps even moral values or law. Make sure you pose your question in a way that tries to avoid these topics by focusing on economic elements of the question. E.g. you could ask how automation can affect employment, and then you can use the answer to make further inferences about how that impacts human rights as defined by UN, but on this site you should not be asking whether automation affects human rights which is moral/political question that cannot be answered with economics and should be asked on philosophy.se or politics.se.

3. Preferably, before asking question you should make your own search/research first and mention in your question why  you still do not understand something or if you could not find anything on the topic you are interested in at least mention/link articles/books you had look at but did not answered your question.